# Local variable ObjList defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

Tags: java, java-8

Below is my code:

```
List<ObjType> objList = objRepo.findAll();
LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, ()-> "Number of document type found :" + objList.size());
```

Getting error in `objList.size()`. And I can't make objList final.

Comment: Most likely, you can’t make `objList` final, because you are assigning a different value to this variable at some later point in the code. This assignment is also the reason why this variable is not effectively final.

Comment: If that's your code, you can certainly make it final.  Even if it's a snippet, you can certainly make it final by instead using a new variable at the point of the second assignment.  Or use the trick in hev1's answer, but it generally indicates poor design.  You could probably also just pass a String rather than create a lamdba that serves no purpose, but it depends on the logger interface you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely reassigning a value to `objList`, which makes it not effectively final. To remedy this, you could create another variable to which you assign `objList`, whose value you never change.

```
List<ObjType> objList = objRepo.findAll();
final List<ObjType> temp = objList;//must be final or effectively final
LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, ()-> "Number of document type found :" + temp.size());
```